# Sharepoint list event

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, splistitem

Is there a event which is raised when permission of a sharepoint list item is changed. 
For instance permission is granted or revoked on a list item

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there is no build in permission-relaited events for list/web/site/users/groups/etc.

As a "might be solution" you can use SPChangeQuery class and queries against necessarily objects. For example, this trick might be used with custom timer job +  SPChangeQuery queries to handle user permissions/groups or group changes as you have quite interesting stuff like GroupMembershipAdd/GroupMembershipDelete or RoleDefinitionAdd/RoleDefinitionDelete and so on in result sets.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use [SPItemEventReceiver.ItemUpdating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventreceiver.itemupdating) and [SPItemEventReceiver.ItemUpdated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventreceiver.itemupdated) events. If you look how to cahnge item permissions you can see that item.Update() method is invoked.

```
SPRoleAssignment roleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(principal);
SPRoleDefinition roleDefinition = web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(roleType);
roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(roleDefinition);

item.RoleAssignments.Add(roleAssignment);
item.Update();
```